# How to call an external API with vertx and return data to java object

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to create a vertx client that calls an external API and gets data using a Java model.

An example of what I want to do is this, below is just a rough work

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

// Send a GET request
client
  .get(8080, "mytour.mycompany.com", "/getRusult?pricemin=0&priceMax=1000&beach=true....etc")
  .send(ar -> {
    if (ar.succeeded()) {
      // Obtain response
      HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
```

mytour is an external API and I want to return the data gotten from the call to my java class already designed for this. The java class below is not completely displayed for brevity but it follows the builder pattern principles. I want to the data gotten from API call to this class.

```
public class Tour {

    private Departure departure;
    private Arrival arrival;
    private TourType tourType;
    private Hotel hotel;
    private Beach beach;
 private Tour() {
        }
```

I am not sure how to go about it any ideas, please. 
At this point here is what i did in other to get tour object from Buffer any idea how to do this ?

```
    public Tour clientTest() {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

// Send a GET request
        client
            .get("https://www.mytour.com/tariffsearch/getResult?" +
                "priceMin=0&priceMax=1500000&currency=533067&nightsMin=6&nightsMax=8" +
                "&hotelClassId=269506&accommodationId=2&rAndBId=15350&tourType=1&" +
                "locale=ru&cityId=786&countryId=1104&after=01.08.2018&before=01.08.2018&" +
                "hotelInStop=false&specialInStop=false&version=2&tourId=1285&" +
                "tourId=12689&tourId=12706&tourId=143330&tourId=9004247&" +
                "tourId=4433&tourId=5736&tourId=139343&tourId=4434&tourId=12691&" +
                "tourId=21301&tourId=12705&tourId=149827&tourId=4151426&hotelClassBetter=true&" +
                "rAndBBetter=true&noTicketsTo=false&noTicketsFrom=false&searchTypeId=3&" +
                "recommendedFlag=false&salePrivateFlag=false&onlineConfirmFlag=false&contentCountryId=1102")
            .send(ar -> {
                if (ar.succeeded()) {
                    // Obtain response
                    HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
                    Tour tour = (Tour) response.body();

                }
             });
    }
```

Comment: the broad strokes seem ok... what exactly is the question?

Comment: ok i want to return the data from the API call to my Tour class :)

Comment: @hsl how can return the values of the call to tour object

Comment: @hsl i edited the question

Comment: have you looked at the documentation for the `HttpResponse` interface? - https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/HttpResponse.html

Comment: yes i have seen it, it says we can use >T or Buffer to get data from response but im not sure how to use it and how do i then use my tour object

Comment: I have updated my answer to give more details to what i have done but doesnt get data from API

Answer (score 2):

> I want to return the data from the API call to my Tour class

Instead of casting a `response.body()` into `Tour` type like that:

```
HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
Tour tour = (Tour) response.body();
```

you should convert `body` into an object (`POJO`). You can do that in at least a few ways.
First, take a look at the JavaDoc of the Vert.x `HttpResponse` class here: https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/HttpResponse.html. We have e.g. method like: `response.bodyAsString()`. Once we've got response body as a `String` and assuming that this `String` contains a response in a JSON data format, we can convert this `String` into our object e.g. using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library or another solution.

For example:

```
HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
String bodyAsString = response.bodyAsString();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Tour tour = gson.fromJson(bodyAsString, Tour.class);
```

After that, when `Tour` object is compatible with JSON HTTP response you should have your response data mapped into the `Tour` object.

I don't know the structure of your HTTP response. If `Tour` object is not compatible with HTTP response, then you should create another object - e.g. `TourResponse`, which will be compatible with this response and create a mapper, which will convert `TourResponse` into `Tour` object.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are asking and for the most part I use the reactive version of the methods for my calls.  The reasoning for this is to process the data as though it was a stream rather than handling potential nested callbacks.

Example Kotlin code:

```
webClient.get(PORT, URL)
   .rxSend()
   //convert to observable stream
   .toObservable()
   //get responsebody as a jsonarray of objects
   .map { response: HttpResponse<Buffer> ->
          response.bodyAsJsonArray().toMutableList() as List<JsonObject>}
   //segment the array into a stream of single object                
   .flatMap { objs: List<JsonObject> -> Observable.fromIterable(objs)}
   //convert each object the json object stream into a java object
   .map {entry:JsonObject -> Json.decode(entry, Tour.javaClass)}
```

After this code executes you would have an `Observable<Tour>` which you could stream through and do any processing you want to on the Tour Objects or you could just call `toList()` to convert to `Single<List<Tour>>` and in the subscribe method handle returning the response back to the caller.

If you have any questions let me know!